# How to destroy jqPhotoSwipe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to destroy the `jqPhotoSwipe` (https://github.com/ergec/jQuery-for-PhotoSwipe) gallery after `uikit filter` in order to update the `index`.

Here is the method to `destroy` : http://photoswipe.com/documentation/api.html

But I didn't managed...

**JS** :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mosaic = $('.js-filter li');
    mosaic.jqPhotoSwipe({
        forceSingleGallery: true
    });
});
$('[uk-filter]').on('afterFilter', function() {
     // destroy PhotoSwipe here and build another one
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/769f5au4/58/)

Thanks you for help!

Comment: You've just asked [**this ~7 hours ago**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099156/destroy-photoswipe).

Comment: Yes but no reply.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem ? Your jsfiddle seems to work...we click on the filters...and it filter the images ?

Comment: @Pierre     If you choose 'category 2' there is only 2 img the index's gallery give 6 img. So l'd like to update dynamically the index after filter clicking

Comment: @Joe278 not sure to understand ... in the index gallery having 6 image, there are 2 images with data-color=lorem...and when we click on 'category 2' we correctly see these 2 images...
What do you mean by "update dynamically the index" ? display the good related images when you click on the filter ? Or refresh completely the 6 images index ?

Comment: @Pierre After clicked category 2, l want to have only the 2 img from the category 2 in the lightbox.  Same for category 1, and if we return on 'all', so every img in the photoswipe lightbox! Do you see what l wanna mean?

Comment: Ah yes i see now the problem ;-)

Comment: Seems that you can add/edit/slides with pswp.items.push({
    src: "path/to/image.jpg", 
    w:1200,
    h:500 
});  we should do a JS that removes all slides except those from the current filter...

Comment: @Pierre Could you show me the way in my fiddle please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pswp = function() {
        var mosaic = $('.js-filter li');
        mosaic.jqPhotoSwipe({
            forceSingleGallery: true,
        });
    };
    pswp();
    $('[uk-filter]').on('afterFilter', function() {
        pswp = null;
        var mosaic = $('.js-filter li:visible');
        mosaic.jqPhotoSwipe({
            forceSingleGallery: true,
        });

    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/769f5au4/70/)